# python: multiprocessing jointly with mpi4py

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, mpi4py

I have a project that is intensive on the side of data handling. I am working on a cluster. I have a problem and I would like to understand which existing libraries for parallelization I can use.

Let's say that

- each node has a memory of 128 GB and 16 CPUs
- I would like the read 500 GB of data
- each node will read a fraction of the data
- each node will communicate to the other nodes which piece of data it needs and collect information for each other node.

I would implement this part with `mpi4py`. After that,

- I would like to do a computation  using all the CPUs in the node using `multiprocessing` module.

I think this last point is called multithreading.

I know that when writing code in C it is possible to use jointly `openMP` and `MPI`, I would like to find an analogous parallelization strategy for python.